# How to fix "520002 Internal Error" response of GetPaymentOptions API?

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am supporting eCommerce project that uses PayPal Adaptive Payments. Suddenly, GetPaymentOptions production API began to respond with 520002 Internal Error. The same Sandbox API works fine, but production one crashes with that error. Official documentation has no information about this error. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?